# JUNIT AssertThatThrownBy Capture Return Value

Tags: java, junit, lambda, assertj

I try to test exception thrown by a method like this:

```
Assertions.assertThatThrownBy( () ->  myMethod(paramA, paramB))
      .isInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class).hasMessage(error);
```

However the problem is I still need to make more assertions on the return value of `myMethod()` without having to invoke it again separately. Since it is a lambda, I cannot assign the return value to external variable without a compile error.

How do I capture and make assertions on the return value of `myMethod()` without having to make another call?

Comment: how can the method throw an exception AND return a value? One or the other, but not both

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Lolz. I must be have been smoking something this morning! :) Thanks for pointing it out.